# Why does QGIS 3.2 "native:extractvertices" algorithm not work properly in standalone script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I execute standalone python code (almost identical to the code in the accepted [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/35561)):

The output file does not contain data, and I get this error message:

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'vertex_index' to 'vertex_ind'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'vertex_part' to 'vertex_par'
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'vertex_part_index' to 'vertex_p_1'

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Field name limitation is known shapefile issue, but why output file is empty and why I get `exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`?

Here is input and output shapefiles:

[image]________[image]

**What can cause this problem?**

Here is the code:

```py
import sys

from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication,
     QgsProcessingFeedback,
     QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"G:\test\input.shp", 'my layer', 'ogr')
output = r"G:\test\output.shp"
params = {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'OUTPUT': output,
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)
print(res)
```

Comment: Try with a nightly for 3.2 - there's much more explicit and useful error messages in 3.2

Comment: @ndawson Current latest release (3.2.0-Bonn) gives the same errors.

Comment: Searching for [`-1073741819 (0xC0000005)` in DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=-1073741819+(0xC0000005)&t=ffcm&ia=web) results in many referrals to **memory access violation**, for example: > The exception code 0xc0000005 indicates a memory access violation.
> [...] it looks like the OCX control you're using is performing an illegal access to the memory, therefore the system raised the exception and halted the program's execution. [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9e83c5fc-caa4-4d64-82a2-342bda0b8673/exception-code-0xc0000005) ### Some questions arise
- Are

Comment: What happens when you run the algorithm inside QGIS?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn It works just fine see picure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZSih.png

Comment: Thank for your responce, but I don't think this error caused by memory access violation because i can run script in QGIS console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZSih.png

Comment: @Mr.Che Maybe QGIS console has access to parts of the memory that are not accessible to the standalone script. I'm by no means an expert in this, so that's just guessing.

Comment: @Mr.Che - Have you tried this using QGIS installed from the standalone installer and not using OSGeo4W? You would have to change the paths accordingly (i.e. `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis", True)` etc.

Comment: just for clarifying your code works well in standalone. Have you tried with another shapefile?

Comment: @FranciscoRaga On which operating system did you test the code? I use Windows 7, PyCharm IDE to launch this standalone code.

Comment: windows 10 and Qgis 3.2

Comment: @FranciscoRaga Sorry, I don't understand which IDE do you use to launch this standalone code? Did you launch this code using QGIS 3.2 console window? Please, share your path variables and batch file content (which you use to launch your IDE) like this one:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5CbNW.png

Comment: I'm lauch the code using a bat,but i will try using pycharm too

Comment: @Mr. Che tested using pycharm your code and work perfectly!you can test your code using other shapefile?If you want share my commets and .bat in a new answer.

Comment: @FranciscoRaga New polygonal shapefile (created using QGIS) give the same error. I think this error caused by wrong PyCharm initialization or wrong paths. Could you please post your paths and PyCharm launcher (*.cmd or *.bat file).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on my comments.

This is my **py3-env.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis


cd /d %~dp0
::python3 extractvertices_standalone.py
::pause
start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

if execute the file directly from .bat work,and if open **pycharm**.This is my project using the **osge4w python interpreter**

[image]

**Run** and pycharm console show :

> {'OUTPUT': 'C:\datos\output\output.shp'}

Open the file to see the result in QGIS.

[image]

Finally the standalone script,it's just like his worst simply by using my [shapefiles](https://qgis.org/downloads/data/?C=M;O=A)

```
#native:extractvertices
import sys

from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication,
     QgsProcessingFeedback,
     QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\datos\shapefiles\regions.shp", 'my layer', 'ogr')
output = r"C:\datos\output\output.shp"
params = {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'OUTPUT': output,
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)
print(res)
```

**Tested using Windows 10 and QGIS 3.2**

I hope this helps you

Comment: It works! Qgis ownz my brain for a month and now it's over. OMG

Comment: Nice!I'm so happy for you.

Comment: The problem were caused by incorrect QGIS libraries initialization while using PyCharm IDE. My old launcher contain such text lines: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5CbNW.png Replacing it with the text in this answer solved the problem.

Comment: @FranRaga Great stuff, still when I run the script I get na error `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms` , I've read stackoverflow on this but no anwser seems to work, I'm using PyCharm 2020.1  / QGIS 3.12, appreciate help!

Comment: Sorry, I've never had that problem. Look here  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308290/49538 or on the QT Forum  https://forum.qt.io/topic/110540/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-find-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-in-qtlib-plugins-platforms

Comment: @FranRaga Two years later and this helped me overcome the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the algorithm in a standalone application, the standard error reporting does not work because the app to handle this is not there.

What you can do is:

1. Run the same algorithm inside QGIS and check what kind of error it reports
2. If that doesn't work (some things from the environment might have an influence...) you can also add your own progress handler in the standalone script which will produce additional feedback.

---

```
import logging
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback

class QgsLoggingFeedback(QgsProcessingFeedback):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        # Also show INFO and DEBUG messages
        # self.handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.handler)

    def reportError(self, msg, fatalError=False):
        logging.log(logging.ERROR, msg)

    def setProgressText(self, text):
        logging.log(logging.INFO, msg)

    def pushInfo(self, info):
        super().pushInfo(info)

    def pushCommandInfo(self, info):
        super().pushCommandInfo(info)

    def pushDebugInfo(self, info):
        super().pushDebugInfo(info)

    def pushConsoleInfo(self, info):
        super().pushConsoleInfo(info)


feedback = QgsLoggingFeedback()
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)
```

Comment: 1. No error while running inside QGIS console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZSih.png 2. Including your code in my code - does nothing (same error message)

Comment: I added some bits and hope it does more now

Comment: Thank you, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Can you try adding the `logging.log()` line also to the `pushXyz()` methods?

Comment: Additionally, you can add a `FileHandler` to have everything in a file https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler