# PyQGIS (3.4) and PyQt5 DLL error

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt5

I have installed the new version os QGIS(3.4) on my computer. I am working in a standalone application of PyQGIS so I need to load PyQt5 components. As a difference with previous versions when I try to load a PyQt5 component like

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

I get this DLL problem:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(stdin)", line 1 in 
Import error: DLL load failed: Not possible to find the specified module.

I have checked if I have some DLL conflicts with other python installations but seems something coming from this module.

Is there anyone who has already faced this problem?

Comment: Are you using win or linux?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289964/49538