# QGIS processing.run() standalone script does not write .prj and .cpg output files of shapefile?

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, clip, osgeo4w

I've created a python standalone script to clip two shapefiles with qgis. I've installed qgis3 with OSgeo4W. The logic is as follows:

```
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

path_qgis_installation = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(path_qgis_installation, True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms()) 


input_file = QgsVectorLayer('.../file_name.shp')
overlay_file = QgsVectorLayer('.../file_name.shp')
output_fil = '.../file_name.shp'

processing.run(
    "native:clip", 
    {
        'INPUT':input_file,
        'OVERLAY':overlay_file,
        'OUTPUT':output_fil
    }
)

qgs.exitQgis()
```

My problem is that when I run the command (only the `processing.run()`) in the python console in qgis or in the osgeo shell, everything works.

When I however run it with my python console (bat script), I only get the following (corrupted) files written to disc: .dbf, .shp, .shp. Missing are .prj and .shx for a complete shapefile.

My suspition is that is has something to do with the paths. At one point I executed `C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/o4w_env.bat` from a location outside of `C:/OSGeo464`) which then even procued the same problem whilst running on the osgeo shell.

Any suggestion what I am missing to load?

Comment: Look at this answer in case it can help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289964/49538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Fran Raga. I was able to solve the issue based on your reference question. For full disclosure, my working code looks like this.

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:/OSGeo4W64

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/bin/o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/bin/qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/bin/py3_env.bat"

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/qgis/bin;%PATH%
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/qgis/qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/qt5/plugins

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/qgis/python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/Python37/lib/site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/Qt5/plugins/platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/qgis

cd /d %~dp0


call ...path/to/shell_scrit.sh
```

The shell script looks like this:

```
python path/to/python/script.py
```

The python script looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

path_qgis_installation = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"
os.environ['path_qgis_installation'] = path_qgis_installation
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['path_qgis_installation'], True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

input_file = QgsVectorLayer('.../file_name.shp')
overlay_file = QgsVectorLayer('.../file_name.shp')
output_fil = '.../file_name.shp'

processing.run(
    "native:clip", 
    {
        'INPUT':input_file,
        'OVERLAY':overlay_file,
        'OUTPUT':output_fil
    }
)

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: Fine! you are welcome ;)