# Using PyQGIS in PyCharm

Tags: pyqgis, installation, pycharm

I'm referring to this post:

> [Why does QGIS 3.2 "native:extractvertices" algorithm not work properly in standalone script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286281/why-does-qgis-3-2-nativeextractvertices-algorithm-not-work-properly-in-standa)

as part on creating startup file `py3-env.bat` for opening PyCharm with PyQGIS works:

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2020.1\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis


cd /d %~dp0
::python3 scratch.py
::pause
start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

I have:

QGIS 3.12.1 installed in: `C:\OSGeo4W64`

PyCharm 2020.1 installed in: `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2020.1\`

After loading PyCharm the interpreter looks like this:

[image]

Now I just would like to run a simple test script like:

```
#native:extractvertices
import sys

from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication,
     QgsProcessingFeedback,
     QgsVectorLayer
)
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\test_pygis\lines.shp", 'my layer', 'ogr')
output = r"D:\test_pygis\verticles.shp"
params = {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'OUTPUT': output,
}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
res = processing.run("native:extractvertices", params, feedback=feedback)
print(res)
```

First the processing module is not found:

[image]

If I try to run the code the second well know error appears in the Python console:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to share the solution I found to integrate PyCharm and PyQGIS in an effective way to run standalone scripts:

**Setup:**

- Windows 10
- QGIS 3.10.4 installed in *c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10*
- PyCharm 2020.1.1 installed in *c:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin\pycharm64.exe*

I can start PyCharm from a batch file (e.g., `pycharm_qgis.bat`) that looks like the following (note that the *QT_PLUGIN_PATH* is slightly different than in your case):

```
@echo off 
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=c:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10
set path=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\system32\WBem

call o4w_env.bat 
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python;%PYTHONPATH%

set PYCHARM="c:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin\pycharm64.exe"
@echo on
start "PyCharm with QGIS knowledge!" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

From the code above, the `o4w_env.bat, qt5_env.bat, py3_env.bat` are the same batch files available in the QGIS binary folder (i.e., in the case of this example `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin`) without any modification. By executing `pycharm_qgis.bat` PyCharm starts and the Python interpreter can be set to `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\python.exe` in order to work with PyQGIS library.

Then, for PyCharm to recognize and use the processing module, one needs to manually add to the interpreter path the folder *%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins*, as shown in the next picture:

[image: Manually add the processing module folder to Python interpreter path]

After that, PyCharm can interact with the processing module:

[image: PyCharm recognies the processing module]

Finally, the following code excerpt replicates your example and uses the `native:extractvertices` algorithm:

```py
import os
import sys

from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProcessingException, QgsProcessingFeedback

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis-ltr", True)
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.initQgis()
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(QgsApplication.prefixPath(), "python", "plugins"))

    import processing
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

    s_lyr_gpk = os.path.join("Shp", "BOUNDARIES3D.shp")
    s_lyr_name = "Boundaries"
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(s_lyr_gpk, s_lyr_name, 'ogr')
    if not lyr.isValid():
        print("Layer {} is not valid".format(s_lyr_name))

    s_alg = 'native:extractvertices'
    out = os.path.join("d:\Data\Output", "extracted_vertices_script.gpkg")

    di_param = {
         "INPUT": lyr,
         "OUTPUT": out
    }
    feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
    try:
        di_out = processing.run(s_alg, di_param, feedback=feedback)
    except QgsProcessingException as e:
        print(e)
        qgs.exitQgis()
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Vertices extracted to file {}.".format(di_out["OUTPUT"]))
    qgs.exitQgis()
```

The above script can be executed directly from PyCharm to get the output geopackage written. No error related to missing QT platform plugin is raised (see image below):

[image: Successful script execution from PyCharm]

Comment: Thank you, give me some time to test!

Comment: Hi Cincin, let me know if any additional code snippet or explanation is needed. Cheers

Comment: I believe it would be beneficial to paste whole code with import that others could copy-paste the solution

Comment: Hi Cincin, I did specify the content of the other bat files included in the file used to start PyCharm. Moreover, I added the import statement to the Python code example and enclosed it in a main function so that it can be executed as a standalone script. Cheers.

Comment: Great stuff! I would only add one path to Interpreter paths: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis-ltr\python` , I've seen it in other solutions and after adding this one, everything started to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @fastest, can you tell me please how does the `.bat`-file work?

Comment: @cincin21: thank you, I am glad I could help! The path you mention is indeed needed in the Python interpreter and it is included in my code to start PyChrarm (i.e., the 4th last line ```set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python;%PYTHONPATH%```.

@Taras: the ```.bat``` file to start PyCharm can be executed by double clicking on it. Afterwards, PyCharm should start and be already informed about the paths to the PyQGIS library. Please, let me know if more information are required. 

Cheers

Answer (score 11):

The Most simply solution without the need to set an own bat-script I have found in the comments of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qm0PCw9v5lI

Just add a new Python Interpreter within PyCharm and select the file `python-qgis-ltr.bat` which you can find within the bin folder of your QGIS installation directory. All the variables in relation to this QGIS installation are set there already.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. In my installation of qgis 3.22.1 the script is called python-qgis.bat.

Comment: Does this allow PyCharm to recognize QGIS' classes and provide introspection and auto-complete?

Comment: Yes, but it is not including the `processing` module, which makes sense as that is a "plugin" to the rest, requires an initialized QgsApplication anyways and does not have much to auto-complete and introspect anyways.

Comment: If I configure it like this, it seems as if it works properly. However, it doesn't update the view of the open QGIS instance, e.g. no layer are added to the TOC. Is this correct, or did I miss here something?

Comment: @i.i.k.: This is not a way to remotely control an already running, independent QGIS. You are able to breakpoint and manipulate a QGIS instance spawned from PyCharm though.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Yeah, in the meantime, I learned, that you can refer to the running project only if you run the code inside of QGIS, otherwise you will get an error in Pycharm. I have given my actual setup below.

Answer (score 4):

System Windows
QGIS 3.28 Firenze

For me I seem to be able to use the qgis functionality as well as the processing plugin in PyCharm when I do the following:

1. Set the project interpreter in Pycharm to use the batchfile under `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.28.3/bin/python-qgis.bat`.

[image]

2. Add manually the path `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.28.3/apps/qgis/python/plugins` to the interpreter path

[image]

3. In your python script, to be able to use the algorithms from the processing plugin, import all functionality from the qgis.core module as well as the processing module and initialize it.

```
from qgis.core import *

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
```

I just tried this out without any deeper knowledge about what I'm actually doing here, and didn't had the time since yesterday to do more research on it yet, but it works for me so far.

Comment: It works beautify! Thank you for all the details. However, I have a tiny question. If I would like to install additionally a certain module, let's say `geopy`, how should it be executed? Do you know, is it possible to have the PyQGIS functionality within a `venv`?

Comment: @Taras I'm very sure, this must be possible. Mh, I'm using conda virtual environments, and I'm using pyqgis generally in Jupyter Notebooks and rarely in PyCharm anymore. In conda you can install pyqgis in your environment with this command: ```conda install qgis=3.28.5 --channel conda-forge```. Maybe you can adjust it to venv? The relevant venv should then be able to be set as the interpreter in Pycharm. In this venv you could also install geopy then.

Comment: Nice idea! Thank you :)

Comment: Also can be useful: https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/conda/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622661/import-qgis-modules-into-python-anaconda