# Open QGIS project from PyCharm or other Python IDE

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have QGIS project and Python script.
I know how use QGIS Python console to run script.
Is there any way to open a QGIS project in PyCharm and to run the Python script there?

Comment: Can this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362874/using-pyqgis-in-pycharm-2020 help you?

Comment: Check out https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#new-standalone-console-tool-for-running-processing. It allows users to run processing algorithms (both built-in, and those provided by plugins) directly from the console.