# Setup QGIS in PyCharm

Tags: pyqgis, pycharm

I had been working with PyCharm 2019 with QGIS, and the setup was working fine,

Now I've upgraded PyCharm to 2022.2.4 Pro, and QGIS core modules are not able import.

Here is my bat file. I am using QGIS Version 3.16 and PyCharm version 2022.2.4 Pro.

```
@ECHO off

set OSGEO4W_ROOT="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16"

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.22.2.4\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Comment: No need for a custom .bat file anymore, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428577/51035

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PyQGIS in PyCharm 2020](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362874/using-pyqgis-in-pycharm-2020)

Comment: pyqgs-qgis.bat file as interpreated used but still unable to import the modules

Comment: Did you wait until PyCharm was done indexing? What exactly do you mean by "unable to import the modules"? Syntax highlighting? Or launch a script from inside PyCharm?

Comment: indexing done. when imporing "from qgis.core import QgsProject" in pycharm its showing can not find the reference "QgsProject" in __init__.py

Comment: Hmm, I have had similar issues with the very latest PyCharm version (and a custom .bat file like yours actually). If you have the time, try a build from 2021 from https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/other.html it *might* just fix it.