PyQGIS standalone application with setting dir path and ini file
I want to use PyQGIS from PyCharm to debug and test.
For this I need that my script use my qgis3.ini file to get credential. This one is in
C:\Users\guigu\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS but when I launch my script from pycharm, it use another one in C:\Users\guigu\AppData\Roaming\python3\profiles\default\Unknown Organization\python3.ini.
My script is very simple :
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
print(app.qgisSettingsDirPath())
#C:/Users/guigu/AppData/Roaming/python3\profiles\default/

I try this but I have the same result :
app = QgsApplication([], False, r"C:\Users\guigu\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\")

How to configure my script to have access to my ini file and credentials?

I cannot reproduce the problem described. If I specify the profile path in the QgsApplication constructor, it works. How did you start PyCharm? I use these instructions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362874/using-pyqgis-in-pycharm but I don't know if that could have anything to do with it.
